# Life of elements in an array of android project

Tags: android

I have arrays which I populate in one activity of the android project. Then I quit that activity to go to another activity. If I come back to activity 1, then will the array still hold values in them or would the values have been gone?

Answer (score 0):

depends on if the system needed those resources to do something else. If it did then no your array will be gone. If it didn't then yes your array will still hold all of the same values.

See: [Lifecycle of an Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)